# If elif else construct and full DRY conform

Tags: python, dry

first of all I am sorry for the bad title but I didn't know what would be appropriate. I am looking for a better syntax for the following block so that I am not repeating myself.

- self.rulerMajorTickLabel and self.rulerMinorTickLabel can either be True or False
- self.rulerMajorTickWidth and self.rulerMinorTickWidth can only be a positive float

  ```
  if self.rulerMajorTickLabel and self.rulerMinorTickLabel:
      if self.rulerMajorTickWidth > self.rulerMinorTickWidth:
          halfTickHeight = self.rulerMajorTickWidth / 2
      else:
          halfTickHeight = self.rulerMinorTickWidth / 2
  elif self.rulerMajorTickLabel:
      halfTickHeight = self.rulerMajorTickWidth / 2
  elif self.rulerMinorTickLabel:
      halfTickHeight = self.rulerMinorTickWidth / 2
  else:
      halfTickHeight = 0
  ```

Thanks you very!

Comment: This is a very general question and there's really not enough information here for us to help you conform to DRY principles. I would suggest starting by considering how you can factor out the major vs minor ideas into a couple of methods and go from there.

Comment: Also, what are the potential values when they are not `True`? Can the value be `None`? Would they be undefined as an attribute? Can they be `False`? Or is it simply `0`?

Comment: self.rulerMajorTickLabel and self.rulerMinorTickLabel can either be True or False self.rulerMajorTickWidth and self.rulerMinorTickWidth can only be a positive float. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a few things here to make it work elegantly, so you might want to make sure of that somewhere else in the code. My assumptions:

- `self.rulerMajorTickWidth` and `self.rulerMinorTickWidth` are either a positive number, or equal to zero
- They are both defined as attributes and looking for them will not throw an error
- You want just the larger of the two to divide by 2

Assuming all that, you can simply do:

```
halfTickHeight = max(self.rulerMajorTickWidth, self.rulerMinorTickWidth) / 2
```

If their "false" value however is either None or undefined, it's more complicated. That's why I suggest making sure in other places in the code that it's either 0 or an integer/float. If they are actually the boolean `False` you can `float()` them to equal 0

Edit: Because I just noticed the labels are different than the width parts, you can still preform all of your checks more easily by doing this:

```
tmpMajor = self.rulerMajorTickWidth if self.rulerMajorTickLabel else 0
tmpMinor = self.rulerMinorTickWidth if self.rulerMinorTickLabel else 0
halfTickHeight = max(tmpMajor, tmpMinor) / 2
```

Which is equivalent to all your `if...elif...else` clauses from before

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment